# Djanfo : CSS not full loading in my server

Tags: html, css

I'm doing a `django` project and my `CSS` file is not showing everything
for example, I'm trying to put a background image and it's not working and it generates no error

I attach my `CSS` file and my code in `base.html`

```html
<body id="p" style="background-image: url({% static 'assets/background.jpg' %}')"></body>
```

Comment: style css : <style type="text/css">
a:link   {  color: red }
a:visited   {  color: maroon }
a:active   {  color: yellow }
body   {  color: white;
background-color: black;
#p{background-image: url(assets/background.jpg);
}
</style>

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should see if your style tag sis warpped in the head tag.Tehn you should make sure that your syle tag is correctly formatted

**Here is an example:**

```
<head>
<!-- this is how to link a style sheet -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
</head>
```

---

Next you should check that the image is being loaded corectly in the css and that you arent making any mistakes.I noticed that you tried loading the image in the comments into a `<p>` tag rather load it into the whole body or a div

**Here is an example of how you should use the css:**

```css
body {
  background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/JggW3.png')
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<html lang="en">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Page Title</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
<head>
<body id="p" style="background-image: url({% static 
'https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmuok.png' %}')">
</html>
```

---

And lastly if all else fails try doing a CSS .basiaclly a CSS reste works bcause browsers have differences in how they render CSS and often have defaults that may cause things to render differently. Basically a CSS reset sets all defaults, like padding to zero

**Here is the CSS reset code:**

```
/* CSS reset */
body,div,dl,dt,dd,ul,ol,li,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,pre,form,fieldset,input,textarea,p,blockquote,th,td { 
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
html,body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
table {
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border-spacing:0;
}
fieldset,img { 
    border:0;
}
input{
    border:1px solid #b0b0b0;
    padding:3px 5px 4px;
    color:#979797;
    width:190px;
}
address,caption,cite,code,dfn,th,var {
    font-style:normal;
    font-weight:normal;
}
ol,ul {
    list-style:none;
}
caption,th {
    text-align:left;
}
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
    font-size:100%;
    font-weight:normal;
}
q:before,q:after {
    content:'';
}
abbr,acronym { border:0;
}
css
```

Comment: i did this with load static
<body id="p" style="background-image: url({% static 'assets/background.jpg' %}')"></body>